# All requests say "text/html", even though I set res.contentType

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, content-type

So, I've got this simple little Express app running, it determines whether to add ".html" or not.  That's pretty much the base of what the script does. Here is the script:

```js
var app = require("express")(),
    cproc = require("child_process"),
    http = require("http").Server(app),
    fs = require("fs"),
    mime = require("mime")
    __webdir = __dirname + "/web",
    mcs = null;

app.get("*", function(req, res){
  var getloc = __webdir + req.originalUrl,
      llcurl = getloc.split("/")[getloc.split("/").length-1],
      modloc = null;

  if (llcurl.match(/\./g)) {
    modloc = getloc;
  } else if (llcurl === "") {
    modloc = getloc + "start.html";
  } else {
    modloc = getloc + ".html";
  }

  res.send(fs.readFileSync(modloc).toString());
  res.contentType(mime.lookup(modloc));
});
```

Although when I include a CSS file or JavaScript file with HTML like so:

```
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

In the "Network" tab of Google Chromium's developer tools, it says the content-type is `text/html`, which obviously isn't true.

As you can see at the bottom I have

```
res.contentType(mime.lookup(modloc));
```

Although `mime.lookup` does return the MIME type, everything still is `text/html` in Chrome's Network menu.

**Extra info for understanding**

So, my root is `node_base` where `app.js` is stored...  So it's in `node_base/app.js`

The HTML files are stored in `node_base/web/`

The JS and CSS files are in `node_base/web/static/`

Comment: Any particular reason for not using express.static? It's meant for the purpose of serving static files.

Comment: @SecondRikudo Sorry, quite new to NodeJS and Express.  I'll look at that in the docs.

Comment: You don't have to apologize to me. I'm not judging you :)

Comment: Two suggestions: stream the file instead of loading it all into memory first, and move the `res.contentType()` to *before* you start writing data to the response stream.

Comment: @mscdex, right, I got it all working because I redid everything.  But, you can write that as an answer if you want.